# Without access to the FTP, how can I fix the index page?

Tags: errors

The company I work for decided that I am now the "website owner", but will not grant access to the FTP files. The index page looks like the theme or CSS is broken. I do have Backup Buddy installed and I am not entirely certain on how to revert back to the previously saved index page, or if restoring that version is everything I need to do (maybe the problem is somewhere else?). I found out there is no error log file. I just installed the Error Log Viewer plugin and am not receiving a log just yet.

The website index page is broken only on the HTTP version: 
http://www.perfect365.com

The HTTPS works fine: 
https://www.perfect365.com

Comment: Check the console, there are some 404 errors. You could activate a different theme through wp-admin to see if it's possibly a theme issue, and you can deactivate plugins to see if it's them. If you can't solve it that way, they're just going to have to provide FTP access or live with a broken site. Also, it's not good to be able to access a site through both http and https - you need to be able to edit .htaccess to force SSL. As a workaround you could try a plugin that forces SSL.

Comment: The key here was forcing HTTPS. I downloaded Force HTTPS and that fixed the issue. I really need the team to make the real change on the files instead of being reliant on a plug in. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your subsequent comments indicate the problem was fixed, you didn't mention 'how' you fixed the problem.

So I have added this answer for anyone else wandering by this question.

But if the issue is not forcing HTTPS, then this is more properly done with settings in your HTACCESS file (which someone with file access will have to do).

A generic htaccess fix is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will rewrite all requests to HTTPS, no matter what URL is requested. It should be placed at the top of your htaccess file, before the WordPress block.